# Can I dynamically create Kendo Grid via Controller?

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have been using Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX where I dynamically create a RadGrid in the code-behind. I have now converted the solution to an MVC (Razor) application with Kendo UI but I cannot fathom how to create the Grid dynamically on the fly?

Before the application starts the Grid will have no properties other than a Name e.g. 'gridView' which I need to reference in the Controller to associate database fields to the grids' properties. I will also need to dynamically add Column Headers and a datasource too.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked this doc?:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/index

You can write this type of code directly in the razor view (.cshtml)
e.g.: Html.Kendo().Grid()
        .Columns(columnsConfiguratorAction)
        .Columns(editColumnConfiguratorAction)
...
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSourceConfiguratorAction)...